# Parallelizing text matching with thousands of patterns

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, benchmarking

I've been inspired by [mold's speed](https://github.com/rui314/mold) to add multicore processing to my usecase where a line of text is matched against thousands of patterns. The patterns have several types: regex, substring, exact match, begin of line and a couple of others. Because there are thousands of patterns to match, logically it should be possible to tap into the power of multicore processing.

However after many hours of implementing and benchmarking, at best I can match the single core implementation, at worst be slower. TBB's documentation does mention that a task needs to take long enough to do before it makes sense to parallelise it - is it truly the case for this and it's a dead end here?

Benchmarking code:

```cpp
    ankerl::nanobench::Bench benchmark;
    benchmark.title("Implementations")
        .minEpochIterations(2000)
        .warmup(100)
        .relative(true);

    benchmark.run("plain for loop", [&] {
        QList<TTrigger*> list;

        for (auto trigger : mParallelizableTriggers) {
            if (trigger->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line)) {
                list.append(trigger);
            }
        }
    });

    benchmark.run("std::copy_if", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        std::copy_if(
            std::execution::par_unseq,
            begin(mParallelizableTriggers),end(mParallelizableTriggers),
            back_inserter(output),
            [subject, data, line](TTrigger* trigger) -> bool {
                return trigger->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
            }
        );
    });

    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for_each, no acc.", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for_each(mParallelizableTriggers, [subject, data, line](TTrigger* trigger) -> bool {
            return trigger->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
        });
    });



    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, automatic grain", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size()),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            }
        );
    });

    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, 10 grainsize", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size(), 10),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            },
            tbb::simple_partitioner()
        );
    });

    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, 100 grainsize", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size(), 100),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            },
            tbb::simple_partitioner()
        );
    });

    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, 1000 grainsize", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size(), 1000),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            },
            tbb::simple_partitioner()
        );
    });


    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, 10000 grainsize", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size(), 10000),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            },
            tbb::simple_partitioner()
        );
    });


    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, 100000 grainsize", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size(), 100000),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            },
            tbb::simple_partitioner()
        );
    });

    benchmark.run("tbb::parallel_for, affinity scheduler", [&] {
        std::vector<TTrigger*> output;
        output.reserve(size(mParallelizableTriggers));
        static tbb::affinity_partitioner affinity_partitioner;

        // semantically incorrect as it doesn't store all results in the output vector
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, mParallelizableTriggers.size()),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) {
                for(int i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i) {
                    mParallelizableTriggers.at(i)->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
                }
            },
            affinity_partitioner
        );
    });

    benchmark.run("QtConcurrent filtered.results()", [&] {
        // can't use blockingFiltered until Qt6 due to a bug in Qt5: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-94463
        auto list = QtConcurrent::filtered(mParallelizableTriggers, [subject, data, line](TTrigger* trigger) -> bool
        {
            return trigger->matchWithoutProcessing(subject, data, line);
        }).results();
    });
```

`matchWithoutProcessing` and the methods it calls can be found in https://github.com/vadi2/Mudlet/blob/multithreaded-triggers/src/TTrigger.cpp#L1563 and https://github.com/vadi2/Mudlet/blob/multithreaded-triggers/src/TriggerUnit.cpp#L1563.

Results: https://gist.github.com/vadi2/b6bbc3dbd2e52132bd7e5802bc0b559a

Comment: Parallelization at the granularity of ~100 is generally not great. It can scale a bit on some platforms (eg. a linux platform with a 4 core mainstream processor) while being actually slower in parallel on others (a windows machine with 2 server processors of both 32 cores). To scale well at such granularity, you need a pool of active threads and a low-latency (and scalable) synchronization mechanisms (typically based on atomics). Besides this, are you sure a `back_inserter` can be used in a parallel loop safely? Moreover, what are the type off `subject`, `data` and `line`?

Comment: `char* subject`, `const QString& data`, `int line`.

Honestly I'm not sure how granularity entirely works because the TBB docs start using the concept without really defining it. Does it mean how many iterations a single 'job' on a single 'core' will do?

> Besides this, are you sure a back_inserter can be used in a parallel loop safely?

Not sure, and the `tbb::` implementation isn't yet accumulating results either, so it'll be slower with that in.

Comment: The concept of "granularity" is basically how big a chunk of work you can pass to a thread, in terms of computation time by the thread.  (Especially relative to communication latency between threads/cores).  e.g. if it takes 100 ns to add something to a queue and have another thread see it and start working on it, then it does its work for some number of microseconds, then stores the results and a flag that it's done, and maybe 50 ns later the main thread notices.  If the time spent doing work it anywhere near as low as 150 ns, you're spending a lot of time waiting.

Comment: 50 ns inter-core latency is reasonable on a fast "client" chip like Skylake desktop/laptop; can be higher on server chips.  And that's if the other thread is spinning in a loop looking for a result; if it has to wake up a core from a sleep state, that might be microseconds.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "at the granularity of ~100 us" (the "us" was missing). For the `back_inserter`, I advise you to resize the vector first and use a basic iterator. The return value of `std::copy_if` can be used to know the actual size. Then, you can resize the vector to its true size. If most items are not copied and the vector is huge, the default initialization of `std::vector` may introduces a visible overhead.

Comment: Spending a lot of time waiting is what is likely happening in my case. I don't fully understand the "a pool of active threads and a low-latency (and scalable) synchronization mechanisms (typically based on atomics)" approach, but shouldn't it be possible to just divide the amount of work by the amount of processors and let each thread run to completion? Sure it won't be perfectly optimal if one finishes before another, but in my case it would make more sense than trying to optimise this, wouldn't it?

Comment: @VadimPeretokin The thing is that there is many ways "to just divide the amount of work by the amount of processors". Runtimes and libraries like the TBB provide basic tools that works well when the computation time is relatively big to the overhead they introduce. In your case, the computation time is small. Thus, if you want a proper parallel speed up, then you need to reduce the overhead. You can do that by reimplementing what such runtimes/libraries does in a more specific way (so it can be more efficient).

Comment: @VadimPeretokin For example, you cannot pay the cost of creating/joining threads every time a parallel-for is done since the time to create them is typically in the range 10~1000 us. Using a *thread pool* remove this overhead from the *critical path*. But this is not the only source of overhead: sleeping threads can take a long time to wake-up when they passively sleep (using syscalls) due to the overhead of *syscalls* but also the cost of *context switches*. To remove this overhead, the thread of the pool needs to actively wait for work to be executed (eg. using atomics without *contention*).

Comment: Thanks, that is very insightful! I will take a look at this at a later time. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I am happy to accept it.